# Gitlab: List all changed files in a MR via API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

How do I list all the changed files in a MR via Gitlab API?
I'm working in a CI project and just want to build the necessary code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the information you need in [GitLab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr-changes)

Specifically, this is an example of response:

```
{
  "id": 21,
...
  "changes": [
    {
    "old_path": "VERSION",
    "new_path": "VERSION",
    "a_mode": "100644",
    "b_mode": "100644",
    "diff": "--- a/VERSION\ +++ b/VERSION\ @@ -1 +1 @@\ -1.9.7\ +1.9.8",
    "new_file": false,
    "renamed_file": false,
    "deleted_file": false
    }
  ]
}
```

You can extract the file names from `changes` -> `new_path`